# How to join two files that are not similar?

Tags: linux, awk, cat

I want to add two files together, which one of them has only 1 column and the other one 10 and I want to add the file with one column in the begging of the other one! and they don't have any similar column!

I tried `join` command but there is a need of a similar column (as I understood) then I tried `cat` command, which works but it doesn't save it as the first column!

so the files format are like this:

File1:

```
probeset_id
AX-76431849
AX-76431844
AX-76431845
```

File2:

```
submitted_id chr snp_pos alleleA alleleB 562_201 562_202 562_203 562_204 562_205 562_206 562_207 562_208 562_209 562_258
"0" "1" "0" "0" "2" "1" "1" "0" "1" "1"
"0" "1" "0" "0" "2" "1" "1" "0" "1" "1"
"0" "1" "0" "0" "2" "1" "1" "0" "1" "1"
```

And I'm trying to have this output:

```
probeset_id submitted_id chr snp_pos alleleA alleleB 562_201 562_202 562_203 562_204 562_205 562_206 562_207 562_208 562_209 562_258
AX-76431849 "0" "1" "0" "0" "2" "1" "1" "0" "1" "1"
AX-76431844 "0" "1" "0" "0" "2" "1" "1" "0" "1" "1"
AX-76431845 "0" "1" "0" "0" "2" "1" "1" "0" "1" "1"
```

When I use the `cat` command I get this:

```
probeset_id
AX-76431849
AX-76431844
AX-76431845
submitted_id chr snp_pos alleleA alleleB 562_201 562_202 562_203 562_204 562_205 562_206 562_207 562_208 562_209 562_258
"0" "1" "0" "0" "2" "1" "1" "0" "1" "1"
"0" "1" "0" "0" "2" "1" "1" "0" "1" "1"
"0" "1" "0" "0" "2" "1" "1" "0" "1" "1"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `paste`:

```
$ paste -d' ' file1.txt file2.txt
probeset_id submitted_id chr snp_pos alleleA alleleB 562_201 562_202 562_203 562_204 562_205 562_206 562_207 562_208 562_209 562_258
AX-76431849 "0" "1" "0" "0" "2" "1" "1" "0" "1" "1"
AX-76431844 "0" "1" "0" "0" "2" "1" "1" "0" "1" "1"
AX-76431845 "0" "1" "0" "0" "2" "1" "1" "0" "1" "1"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ paste -d ' ' file1.txt file2.txt
probeset_id submitted_id chr snp_pos alleleA alleleB 562_201 562_202 562_203 562_204 562_205 562_206 562_207 562_208 562_209 562_258
AX-76431849 "0" "1" "0" "0" "2" "1" "1" "0" "1" "1"
AX-76431844 "0" "1" "0" "0" "2" "1" "1" "0" "1" "1"
AX-76431845 "0" "1" "0" "0" "2" "1" "1" "0" "1" "1"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use *paste*

```
paste -d " " file1.txt file2.txt > result.txt
```

The *-d* flag specifies the delimiter you want between the fields. Default is a tab.